# Check if a curried function is still expecting further arguments

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

I would like to know if it possible to find out how many remaining arguments a curried function is expecting in javascript, if possible, without ever actually calling the function.
I want a function that takes a function and returns if the function is expecting 2 or more remaining arguments.

```
hasSeveralRemainingArguments: fn => bool
```

Let's say I have the functions:

```
const double = x => 2*x;
const inc = x => x + 1;
const divideBy = ({dividor}) => x => x/dividor;
const decrementAndDivideBy = ({dividor}) => x => (x - 1)/dividor;

hasSeveralRemainingArguments(double); // false
hasSeveralRemainingArguments(inc); // false
hasSeveralRemainingArguments(divideBy); // true
hasSeveralRemainingArguments(divideBy({dividor: 5})); // false
hasSeveralRemainingArguments(decrementAndDivideBy); // true
hasSeveralRemainingArguments(decrementAndDivideBy({dividor: 5})); // false
```

The usecase would be a function `foo` which expects an options argument and an array of functions to call. I want to "`pipe`" through the array of functions and input the options argument only to the functions that are actually expecting the argument like in this case `divideBy` and `decrementAndDivideBy`, e.g.:

```
const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((y, fn) => fn(y), x);

const foo = (options = {}) => (fns = []) => pipe(
  fns.map(fn => (
    hasSeveralRemainingArguments(fn) ? 
      fn(options) : 
      fn
  )
);

const bar = (...fns) => {
  const options = {
    dividor: 3
  }; // local, not known to the caller of bar. They just know that they can pass in a function which will receive an options-object, they just don't know what is inside this object.

  return foo(options)(fns);
});

const baz = bar(
  double,
  inc, 
  divideBy,
  decrementAndDivideBy
);

baz(4); // ((4*2 + 1)/3 - 1)/3 = 0.67
baz(10); // ((10*2 + 1)/3 - 1)/3 = 2
```

The `options` argument is not known by the caller of the function `bar`. Otherwise I could input the `options` argument before passing the functions into `bar` but this is unfortunately not possible.

You should also note that `double`, `inc`, `divideBy` and `decrementAndDivideBy` are built to only accept numbers as the argument `x` but this might not always be the case. If possible, I don't want to call the functions and test if the returned value is a function or not but currently I do not see any other way.

I could also pass objects with a function and a boolean "isExpectingOptions" but this would not be very nice/elegant for the person calling `bar`.

Do you have another idea?

Comment: You should just put a `.isExpectingOptions = true` property on the respective functions.

Comment: Why not simply make *all* function expect an option argument (and possibly ignore it)?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, those would both be some workarounds but not as elegant. A flag on a funcion feels weird to me and just ignoring the option argument on many functions is also quite unelegant. In the end I'll probably go with one of those options, if there won't be someone with a better idea...

Comment: There's nothing inelegant about the ignored option parameter. On the contrary, it gives all functions a consistent interface, and all functions in the array will have the same type, allowing you to treat them the same and not having to check their arity.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I'll still leave this question open because I am interested if there is a way to do this.

Comment: There is no way to do that, other than a) explicitly tagging the function or b) parsing its source

Comment: You have this issues in the first place, because you treat your data structure as a tuple rather than an array. An array should contain values of a single type, not of different types, so that you can map over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property of a function?

> The length property indicates the number of parameters expected by the function.

```js
const a = curry((x, y, z) => 42);

a.length       // 3
a(1).length    // 2
a(1)(2).length // 1
```

Comment: That is interesting... didn't know that. You'd have to use the "curry" function for this to work though right? But I think this is the best one so far!

Comment: This seems pretty specific to ramda's `curry` implementation, which explicitly tags every curried function with the `.length` (and also makes them accept multiple arguments at once if called that way). It does not work for `dividor => x => x/dividor`.

Comment: @Bergi I was indeed thinking of Ramda's curry here but I think the point still is valid: it's possible to come up with a _curry_ function that let you query how many arguments are left.

Comment: @Bergi I do however agree that it will probably _never_ work with this form `x => y => z => 42`. The question was about "curried function" so I deliberately left implementation details out of the equation, so I could present one possible answer and let OP figures out if it is worth changing their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, 
you can check the arity of the function,
however this doesn't really work if currying is achieved manually.

```js
const nSum = R.curry((a, b, c) => {
  console.log('nSum.length', nSum.length);
  
  return a + b + c;
});

const uSum = (a) => (b) => (c) => {
  console.log('uSum.length', uSum.length);

  return a + b + c;
};


nSum(1, 2, 3);
uSum(1)(2)(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

You could potentially build a `getArity` function, 
but this would require applying the function to extract the number of its arguments...

```js
const getArity = (fn, arg) => {
  const res = fn(arg);

  return 1 + (
    typeof res === 'function' ? getArity(res, arg) : 0
  );  
};

const uSum = (a) => (b) => (c) => a + b + c;

console.log(
  getArity(uSum, 0),
);

const sum2 = uSum(0);

console.log(
  getArity(sum2, 0),
);
```

This function, also, doesn't really tell you the arity of the function...
but how many time can be curried if we assume it as unary.